# save number of lines of a text file in a variable shell file

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I'm working on terminal and running a `.sh` file and I want to count the lines in another file and save it as a variable to be used in this `.sh` file.
I'm using this command `sed -n '$=' /lines.txt` when I run this it displays the number of lines on terminal but I want to save it in a variable named `numberoflines`. If anyone could advise how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numberoflines=$(sed -n '$=' /tmp/lines.txt)
```